# How to prevent tooltip from creating a vertical scrollbar in table?

Tags: css, tooltip, overflow, z-index, css-tables

I created a table with tooltips embedded in it. Near the bottom of the table, the length of the tooltip hover would reach outside of the bottom of the table and so this creates a permanent vertical scrollbar in the table to fit the tooltip. However I want the tooltip to simply overlap outside of the bottom of the table and get rid of the scrollbar. What am I missing?

I added the code snippet:

```css
/* table */
table.my-table.payment-delivery {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

table.my-table th {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  font-size: 105%;
}

table.my-table th, table.my-table td {
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px dotted white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px;
}

table.my-table th:first-child,
table.my-table td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 150px;
}

table.my-table th:last-child,
table.my-table td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table.my-table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

table.my-table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #606060;
  color: white;
}

table.my-table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #707070;
  color: white;
}

table.my-table tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

table.my-table tbody tr:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) td:first-child {
  font-size: 85%;
}

/*tooltip*/
span.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
}

span.tooltip span {
  opacity: 0.8;
  top: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 23px);
  margin-left: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #800000;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

span:hover.tooltip span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 23px);
  margin-left: -50%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
 <table class="my-table payment-delivery" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Standard<br>fee</th>
        <th><p style="color: #33cc00;">Free delivery<br>from...</p></th>
        <th>Carrier</th>
        <th>Duration</th>
        <th>Door to Door</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Kenya</td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 4<span>EUR: 4<br>GBP: 4<br>KES: 500<br>UGX: 15.000<br>RWF: 4.500<br>TZS: 9.500<br>GHS: 50</span></span></td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 40<span>EUR: 36<br>GBP: 32<br>KES: 5.000<br>UGX: 150.000<br>RWF: 45.000<br>TZS: 95.000<br>GHS: 450</span></td>
        <td>Speedball courier</td>
        <td>1-3 days</td>
        <td><big>✅</big> yep</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>South Africa, Nigeria,<br>Ghana, Uganda,<br>Tanzania, Rwanda,<br>Burundi, Senegal,<br>Botswana, Zambia,<br>South Sudan</td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 25<span>EUR: 22<br>GBP: 20<br>KES: 3.500<br>UGX: 95.000<br>RWF: 28.000<br>TZS: 60.000<br>GHS: 300</span></td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 100<span>EUR: 90<br>GBP: 80<br>KES: 13.500<br>UGX: 375.000<br>RWF: 110.000<br>TZS: 230.000<br>GHS: 1.200</span></td>
        <td>DHL</td>
        <td>3-5 days</td>
        <td><big>✅</big> yep</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EU countries,<br>UK, USA, Canada,<br>India, Saudi Arabia,<br>UAE, Israel,</td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 30<span>EUR: 28<br>GBP: 25<br>KES: 4.000<br>UGX: 110.000<br>RWF: 35.000<br>TZS: 70.000<br>GHS: 350</span></td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 125<span>EUR: 110<br>GBP: 100<br>KES: 16.500<br>UGX: 475.000<br>RWF: 140.000<br>TZS: 300.000<br>GHS: 1.500</span></td>
        <td>DHL</td>
        <td>3-5 days</td>
        <td><big>✅</big> yep</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Japan, South Korea,<br>Singapore, Malaysia,<br>Bangladesh</td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 35<span>EUR: 30<br>GBP: 27<br>KES: 4.700<br>UGX: 130.000<br>RWF: 40.000<br>TZS: 80.000<br>GHS: 400</span></td>
        <td><span class="tooltip">$ 150<span>EUR: 130<br>GBP: 120<br>KES: 20.000<br>UGX: 550.000<br>RWF: 165.000<br>TZS: 350.000<br>GHS: 1.700</span></td>
        <td>DHL</td>
        <td>3-5 days</td>
        <td><big>✅</big> yep</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: It is not the table getting the scrollbar, but the document itself. You tooltip elements are still "there" even in their non-showing state - you used only opacity & visibility to hide them, so they still take the same space they will later on, when you show them. You would need to work with `display: none` or set their height to 0 (and hide overflow), if you do not want them to change dimensions in their hidden state already. But if your table was at the very bottom of the document, then it would still need this "shift" the moment you are trying to display them.

Comment: The table is in the middle of the page so that isn't a problem.

So I tried what you mentioned. When I added `display: none;` to the span.tooltip span section the scrollbar disappears but so does the tooltip. It just doesn't show anymore on hover.

When I added `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;` it didn't change anything in result.

Comment: _"It just doesn't show anymore on hover."_ - of course you also need to _set_ `display: block` on hover again.

Comment: This is great, it made the scrollbar disappear in non-hover state! The scrollbar now only appears in hover state when the tooltip reaches over the bottom of the table. Is it possible to avoid this as well and have the tooltip just flow over the edge without expanding the table?

Comment: It doesn't expand your table, but it _needs to_ expand the document, if there is not enough space left below the table, to display the full tooltip. If what wasn't happening, then your tooltip would simply get cut off at this point. You'll have to make your tooltip not extend down, but in the upwards direction then. If you don't want to apply that generally, for like say the second half of your table rows - then you will have to involve some JavaScript, that does some "measuring" first, and then dynamically decides whether a tooltip should open down or up.

Comment: I'll just extend it upwards. That didn't even occur to me. Thanks a ton!